# How to use Resolve to prove ForAll function

Tags: boolean-computation, proof, resolve

I want to prove that

```
 ∀n ∈ N，Mod[9^n - 8 n - 1, 64] == 0
```

I think I should use `Resolve` to prove it

```
Resolve[ForAll[n, Mod[9^n - 8 n - 1, 64] == 0], Integers]
```

but it doesn't print `True`, which confuses me.

Comment: That statement may not be true. When n = - 55 it is false.

Comment: n need to be positive integers

Comment: you can try this TrueQ[ForAll[n, 
  Mod[9^n - 8 n - 1, 64] == 0 && n > 0 && n \[Element] Integer]] I do not know if it is correct but the answer is false

Comment: It's my modified command: Resolve[ForAll[n, Mod[9^n - 8 n - 1, 64] == 0 && n > 0], Integers] but it print False. and i don't know why

Comment: The proper usage appears to be `Resolve[ForAll[n, n > 0, Mod[9^n - 8 n - 1, 64] == 0]]`, which returns unevaluated.

Comment: Seems to be that `Power[]` is problematic in this case. If we do `Resolve[ForAll[n, n > 0, Mod[9 - 8 n - 1, 64] == 0 ], Integers]` (removing exponent from 9), it evaluates to _False_ correctly. Also the same expression with `Exists` evaluates to _True_